# always one item is selected/highlighted in treeview and listview c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, treeview, treenode

In MDI Child form,

How can I force it so that one item is always selected/highlighted.

When I load the form, I want to see that the first node of the treeview is highlighted, even if I navigate away ie use other child forms, should always one item is highlighted.

Also, same approach I need it to be done on a listview

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While setting `HideSelection` property is necessary to highlight selected items when control is not focused, it is not enough. Situations when item (node) is focused but not selected are perfectly valid and can be achieved by user (and item that focused but not selected is marked only when control is active).

However you can use a simple trick to force focused item be always selected (and thus visible even when control is not active):

```
private void listView_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Focused)
        e.Item.Selected = true;
}
```

Also do not forget to focus first item (node) of your control after populating it, so one item (node) will be always highlighted.